# DataGridView Row Color Change by null value in column

Tags: datagridview, conditional-statements

> **I want to color specific row that contain null value in [Column] in Query. but its not working. kindly correct my mistake in following code please. What i need is to show all the data in datagridview, but want to color only that row which contain null value. OR i need simple code that detect COLUMN [13] null value and color full Row**

```
 private void hgrd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string rf = "SELECT * FROM [Customer Table] WHERE (ClosingDate IS NULL)";
        OleDbCommand rff = new OleDbCommand(rf, nn);
        OleDbDataAdapter aa = new OleDbDataAdapter(rff);
        DataTable bb = new DataTable();
        aa.Fill(bb);
   if (bb.Rows.Count > 0)
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in bb.Rows)
        {
        string rowtype = row.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
            if (rowtype !=null)

            {row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor=Color.Red;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried checking for "" instead of null? I'm pretty sure your .ToString() will throw an error if it actually encounters a null.

Comment: what happens when you run your code? Does your table actually have nulls?